# java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4PreparedStatement.setBinaryStream(JDBC4PreparedStatement.java:96)

Tags: java, jdbc, sqlexception

trying to insert data in database. data is not storing and i am not getting it what is the problem here.

these are the code of error massages to be printed

```
        System.out.println(e.getErrorCode());
        System.out.println(e.getSQLState());
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.out.println(e.getCause());
        System.out.println(e.getNextException());
```

error in console

```
Connection to SQLite has been established.
0
null
null
null
null
```

adding the class for extra understanding in details.

CompanyDetailsController.java

```
    @FXML
private void saveCompanyDetails(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

    String companyName = CompanyNameField.getText();
    String details = detailsField.getText();
    String address = addressField.getText();
    String country = countryField.getValue().toString();
    String city = cityField.getValue().toString();
    String state = stateField.getValue().toString();
    String stateCode = stateCodeField.getValue().toString();
    String pin = pinField.getText();
    String contactNumber = contactField.getText();
    String email = emailField.getText();
    String website = websiteField.getText();
    String gstin = gstinField.getText();
    String pan = panField.getText();
    String tan = tanField.getText();
    String taxtation = textationField.getValue().toString();
    String taxRate = taxRateField.getText();
    String proprietor = proprietorField.getText();
    String aadhaar = aadhaarField.getText();
    String currency = currencyField.getText();
    String companyCode = companyCodeField.getText();
    String pos = posField.getText();

    fis= new FileInputStream(file);

    String sql = "INSERT INTO companyDetails (companyName, additionalDetails, address, country, city, state, stateCode, pinCode, contactNumber,"
            + "email, website,GSTIN, TAN,PAN, taxationType, taxRate, proprietor,adhaarNo,currency,companyCode,POScode,logo,cid) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    try {

        PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstmt.setString(1, companyName);
        pstmt.setString(2, details);
        pstmt.setString(3, address);
        pstmt.setString(4, country);
        pstmt.setString(5, city);
        pstmt.setString(6, state);
        pstmt.setString(7, stateCode);
        pstmt.setString(8, pin);
        pstmt.setString(9, contactNumber);
        pstmt.setString(10, email);
        pstmt.setString(11, website);
        pstmt.setString(12, gstin);
        pstmt.setString(13, tan);
        pstmt.setString(14, pan);
        pstmt.setString(15, taxtation);
        pstmt.setString(16, taxRate);
        pstmt.setString(17, proprietor);
        pstmt.setString(18, aadhaar);
        pstmt.setString(19, currency);
        pstmt.setString(20, companyCode);
        pstmt.setString(21, pos);
        pstmt.setBinaryStream(22,fis);


        pstmt.executeUpdate();

        hf.showDialog("Company Details Added Successfully");
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getErrorCode());
        System.out.println(e.getSQLState());
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.out.println(e.getCause());
        System.out.println(e.getNextException());
    }
}
```

Can Anyone help with it??

Comment: please add the error as text and keep only relevant part of your code sample

Comment: ok doing it. thanks for information

Comment: What JDBC driver are you using? It is possible (though I think unlikely) that it just doesn't set any of these values. Does calling `e.printStackTrace()` give any more useful information?

Comment: @sillyfly SQLITE by the log showed in the question "_Connection to SQLite has been established._".

Comment: using SQLiteStudio 
e.printStackTrace() is showing error... where should i include it in the code section? inside the catch ?

Comment: yes @Jahan, it is a [`Throwable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace%28%29) method.

Comment: By the way : [How do I get the result code from SQLException or PreparedStatement with SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29079582/how-do-i-get-the-result-code-from-sqlexception-or-preparedstatement-with-sqlite). Seems to be an hold problem

Comment: You've got 23 `?`/columns in your query, but you only fill 22 of them with the `PreparedStatement`...

Comment: @fabian  23rd column is cid autoincremented  primary key..

Comment: If you add it to the list of column names/value placeholders, you need to set it. If you want to use the key generated by the db simply leave out this column...

Comment: @AxelH  yes but there is no solution...  
stuck i am :(

Comment: @TamannaJahan can you add in the question the stacktrace you get with `e.printStackTrace()` it could help me answering the problem about the getter not returning anything. As the exception itself, _fabian_ answered already.

Comment: @fabian left the column but didnt work

Comment: You should **remove** the column from the column list **and** parameter list.

Comment: @AxelH  couldn't implement the e.printStackTrace() ... showing some errors

Comment: `catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }` will print the exception in the console, if this is what you call _errors_ this is what I would like to see...

Comment: @AxelH  the error is showing this one for e.printStackTrace()


> java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException
 at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4PreparedStatement.setBinaryStream(JDBC4PreparedStatement.java:96)
>at module.settingSection.companyDetails.CompanyDetailsController.saveCompanyDetails(CompanyDetailsController.java:211)

Comment: That means the `setBinaryStream` method is not supported by your driver. Which is pretty damn important information to include. You might want to update and rephrase your question.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thank u so much for the concern. kind of new here. I will try to improve my knowledge further . :)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel  thanks a lot for the specific direction of the problem. Its working now. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can find in the [github](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sqlite/jdbc4/JDBC4PreparedStatement.java) that the JDBC v4, including some special setters like BLOB, Binaries types, ... are not supported

```
public void setBinaryStream(int parameterIndex, InputStream x, long length)
        throws SQLException {
    // TODO Support this
    throw new SQLFeatureNotSupportedException();
}
```

And for the problem you got in the logs, it is using the [`SQLFeatureNotSupportedException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLFeatureNotSupportedException.html#SQLFeatureNotSupportedException%28%29) constructors with no parameters. The doc says :

> Constructs a SQLFeatureNotSupportedException object. **The reason, SQLState are initialized to null and the vendor code is initialized to 0**. The cause is not initialized, and may subsequently be initialized by a call to the Throwable.initCause(java.lang.Throwable) method.

Comment: Thank you.. I will implement the way of inserting image in a different way. hope the problem will be solved. :)

Comment: @TamannaJahan From a quick search, you can use some alternative for [inserting BLOB in a DB](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/jdbc-read-write-blob/). This could be a start

Comment: thank you so much for the link. It worked perfectly... the problem was setBinaryStream was not supported. had to use setBytes instead.

Comment: @TamannaJahan, yep, has explained, the functionalities for JDBC4 (found in the github linked) are not supported yet on SQLITE. That include `setBinaryStream`. Glad you find the alternative. PS : Don't forget to check [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).